# Can any raster image convert to vector image?

Tags: svg, graphics, vector-graphics

Is it possible to convert any jpg/png image to a vector image like svg format with the exactly same content?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use [Inkskape](https://inkscape.org) .
Here's [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1cZk08x_rAI) how to do that .